# Replace NULL with blank value (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Replace NULL value with blank value

While trying to convert NULL to blank value by using a CASE statement.

Note: `sampCol` is numeric IDs

```
,CASE WHEN sampCol IS NULL THEN '' ELSE sampCol END as sampCol
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing numeric and string values.

A NULL is not an empty string.  It is the absence of value.

Items like this should really be relegated to the presentation layer, but if you must, try the following cheat.

```
...
, concat('',sampCol) as sampCol 
...
```

Comment: would this go under there WHERE statement?

Comment: @PhilK Nope.  This is the column.  I have no idea what your WHERE statement is

Comment: "should really be relegated to the presentation layer"  << 100% agree.  (to the person who wrote the original question...PLEASE get this voodoo conversion out of your datalayer.  this is a presentation concern.

Comment: Sorry, I meant WHERE clause, but yes I just got what you meant. But yeah, that totally worked. Thanks

Comment: Although this does work, this does now mean that 10 < 2, which is just wrong. The caveats have been given here though; this doesn't belong in the RDBMS side of things. But this should definitely not go in the `WHERE` @PhilK. It'll ruin any performance your query had.

Answer (score 5):

This is because a case expression can return one and only datatype according to datatype precedence. You can't convert an empty string a numeric datatype. What you are trying to do sounds like it belongs at the presentation layer, not the data layer. Let NULL happen!!!

Comment: So there's no way to do it?

Comment: There is always a way. But in this case you shouldn't. Your presentation logic does not belong in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Using `COALESCE()` with `CAST()` will help:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(SampCol AS VARCHAR (10)), '') AS SampCol
FROM TestTable
```

Here instead of `VARCHAR (10)`, you can change the required length as per your business need.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a7a7dcf024edc338c1e59cf132855d5)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Shawn May's answer. Three left brackets and only 2 right brackets will never work. 
Try:

```
ISNULL(CAST(sampCol AS VARCHAR(100)),'')
```

Maybe add the field name using `AS` so you can use it in your app.

```
ISNULL(CAST(sampCol AS VARCHAR(100)),'') as samplColName
```

Answer (score 1):

Script to Fix all null values into database

/*By Brian Alvarez Ayala*/
email - brian.alvarez@yahoo.com
website - w w w . a s e s o r i a r e m o t a . c o m

Declare @COLUMN_NAME varchar(40)
Declare @DATA_TYPE varchar(40)
Declare @TABLES_NAMES varchar(40)
Declare @TABLE_SCHEMA varchar(40)
Declare @IS_NULLABLE varchar(3)

Declare @SqlCMD varchar(MAX)
Declare tablas cursor for
select t.TABLE_SCHEMA ,t.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME,c.DATA_TYPE,c.IS_NULLABLE   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  c on c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
open tablas
fetch next from tablas into @TABLE_SCHEMA,@TABLES_NAMES,@COLUMN_NAME,@DATA_TYPE,@IS_NULLABLE
while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin
        if (@DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' or @DATA_TYPE = 'int') and @IS_NULLABLE='YES'
        begin
            set @SqlCMD ='Update ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLES_NAMES + ' set ' + @COLUMN_NAME +' = 0 where ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' is null'
            print @sqlcmd
        end

```
    if (@DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' or @DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' or @DATA_TYPE = 'char') and @IS_NULLABLE='YES'
    begin
        set @SqlCMD ='Update ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLES_NAMES + ' set ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' + ''' ''' + ' where ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' is null'
        print @sqlcmd
    end

    if (@DATA_TYPE = 'bit') and @IS_NULLABLE='YES'
    begin
        set @SqlCMD ='Update ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLES_NAMES + ' set ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' + '''False''' + ' where ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' is null'
        print @sqlcmd
    end

    fetch next from tablas into @TABLE_SCHEMA,@TABLES_NAMES,@COLUMN_NAME,@DATA_TYPE,@IS_NULLABLE
end
```

close tablas
deallocate tablas

Comment: Please, fix the formatting of your answer. Furthermore a little more description would help any reader to better understand your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
    ..CASE WHEN sampCol IS NULL THEN to_number('') ELSE sampCol END as sampCol
```

Comment: to_number('') is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Ah SQL Server.        ..CASE WHEN sampCol IS NULL THEN cast('' as number) ELSE sampCol END as sampCol

Comment: There are functions that handle this exact situation. No need for a `CASE`. For T-SQL, use `ISNULL(CAST(sampCol AS VARCHAR(100),'')` or generic SQL `COALESCE(CAST(sampCol AS VARCHAR(100),'')`.